# useEffect() and array of deeply nested objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks, watermelondb

I am trying to call `useEffect()` whenever `arrayWithDeeplyNestedObjects` changes. `export default compose(...` is part of an offline first database ([watermelonDB](https://github.com/Nozbe/WatermelonDB)) and updates `arrayWithDeeplyNestedObjects` when there is a change in the database. One could expect `useEffect()` to execute, whenever `arrayWithDeeplyNestedObjects` changes, but it is not.  This is beause `useEffect()` only performs a shallo comparison and does not recognize the changes in `arrayWithDeeplyNestedObjects`.

```js
import withObservables from '@nozbe/with-observables';
import {withDatabase} from '@nozbe/watermelondb/DatabaseProvider';
import {compose} from 'recompose';
import {Q} from '@nozbe/watermelondb';

const Foo = ({arrayWithDeeplyNestedObjects}) => {
  console.log('render'); // <-- this renders whenever arrayWithDeeplyNestedObjects is updated

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(new Date()); // <-- this does not render whenever arrayWithDeeplyNestedObjects is updated
    const doSomething = async () => {
        ...
    };
    const data = await doSomething();
    setData(data);
  }, [arrayWithDeeplyNestedObjects]); // <-- this does only perform a shallow compare

    return <SomeNiceUi />
}

export default compose(
  withDatabase,
  withObservables(['arrayWithDeeplyNestedObjects'], ({database}) => ({
    arrayWithDeeplyNestedObjects: database.get(SOME_TABLE).query().observe(),
  })),
)(Foo); <-- subscription das fires everytime an update is made to the database
```

This is how `arrayWithDeeplyNestedObjects` looks like

```
[{"__changes": null, "_isEditing": false, "_preparedState": null, "_raw": {"_changed": "x,y", "_status": "created", "id": "3", "x": 5851, "id_arr": "[\"160\"]", "id": "6wmwep5xwfzj3dav", "y": 0.17576194444444446}, "_subscribers": [], "collection": {"_cache": [RecordCache], "_subscribers": [Array], "changes": [Subject], "database": [Database], "modelClass": [Function SomeTable]}}]
```

The changes to `arrayWithDeeplyNestedObjects` are done in the objects either to `x`, `y` or `id_arr`. The length of `arrayWithDeeplyNestedObjects` can change as well. There might be more (or less) objects of the same structure in there.

How to call `useEffect()` everytime `arrayWithDeeplyNestedObjects` changes?

Comment: Why do you need the useEffect?  If the `console.log('render')` is run when you expect, then that's the right place to invoke `doSomething`, no?

Comment: @jme11 How would I `await` the result of `doSomething()` when doing it where `console.log('render')` is currently?

Comment: I'm not sure can answer that because `doSomething()` is too abstract.  A more concrete example or explanation may help.

Comment: @jme11 Do Something process the data coming from the database.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(new Date());
  const doSomething = async () => {
    ...
  };
  doSomething();
}, [JSON.stringify(arrayWithDeeplyNestedObjects)]);
```

Comment: This is not possible because of the cyclic structure of the object in the array.